# Display local time in report as instead of server time

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, rdlc, reportviewer

The local datetime displays correctly in my rdlc report. But when I upload onto the server, a different datetime is displayed.

If the local report is run at `10 Jun 2014 5:01 AM` the uploaded file in server will say something like `08 Jun 2014 10:17 PM` - How can I ensure the correct time is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a UTC value to the local time through the ToLocalTime method eg:

```
=Today.ToLocalTime()
```